How to remove or reorder IntelliSense entries in VS Code
I have a method in my file called sendMessageToBuffer(). It is the first entry when IntelliSense pops up so when I want to enter send() by typing send and TAB, the long method is entered instead.
Is there a way to force the longer method name to the bottom of the list so it isn't selected by default? Alternatively, is there a way to remove the entry because I never need to type that method name?

Well just type send and then ( instead of TAB. You already found the method you want to use, so why use intellisense further?

would rather give the important function a prefix, such as a_ and refactor the code or rename the specific function afterwards. Unfortunately there is no other option I can think of
